# Launch command after reboot on Raspbian?

Tags: boot, reboot, raspbian

I Have problems with mounting the drives after the reboot. I have a openmadiavault server with 2 HDDs connected via USB 3.1 to the raspberry pi 4. But sometimes they dont mount as they should.
I did this:

```
crontab-e
```

then edited with nano, and added this line

```
@reboot sleep 10 && sudo mount -a
```

(wait 10 seconds and after that, mount all the drives)
But I think I'm not doing this correctly. Can somebody tell me what I am missing?
Thanks

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You do not need to use `&&` , replace with `;`. And do not use `sudo`, just put this in `root` `cron`